# How to wait for the first of the 2: a process and an EventWaitHandle

Tags: c#, process, intptr, waithandle

I want to WaitForMultipleObjects on 2 different types:

- an 'EventWaitHandle'
- a 'Process.Handle' ==> intptr

I don't know how to convert (in the appropriate way) "process.Handle" to a WaitHandle in order to have the following code working:

```
   var waitHandles = new WaitHandle[2];
   waitHandles[0] = waitHandleExit;
   // Next line is the offending one:
   waitHandles[1] = new SafeWaitHandle(process.Handle, false);
   int waitResult = WaitHandle.WaitAny(waitHandles, timeOut);
```

Im getting the error:

```
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeWaitHandle' to 'System.Threading.WaitHandle' ...
```

Anybody know the right way to wait for a process and an EventWaitHandle ?

**Update... Reasons for my choice of answer.**

First of all thanks to all: Jaroen, Slugart and Sriram. All answers were very nice.

- Jaroen solution for a reason I ignored didn't work on my machine. My 'Exited' event never occured (perhaps only on Disposed?).
- Slugart solution worked perfectly and I tried it before I red its answer.
- Sriram solution worked perfectly and I opted for it because I do not create a false EventWaitHandle and seems to be more clean according to my vision.

Thanks a lots!!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could [subclass the WaitHandle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356962/how-can-i-subclass-waithandle) which represents `Process.Handle` and use instance of that `WaitHandle` to wait.

```
public class ProcessWaitHandle : WaitHandle
{
    private readonly Process process;
    public ProcessWaitHandle(Process process)
    {
        this.process = process;
        this.SafeWaitHandle = new SafeWaitHandle(process.Handle, false);
    }
}

var waitHandles = new WaitHandle[2]
{
    waitHandleExit,
    new ProcessWaitHandle(process)
};
int waitResult = WaitHandle.WaitAny(waitHandles, timeOut);
```

Comment: Why `false` on `new SafeWaitHandle`?

Comment: @N-ate that is the `ownsHandle` parameter which will be used to release the underlying handle if true while disposing. Now that we have passed false, it won't dispose the process handle.

Answer (score 2):

You could create your own EventWaitHandle and set it on the [Process.Exited](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited(v=vs.110).aspx) event:

```
var waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);
process.Exited += (sender, e) => waitHandle.Set()
waitHandles[1] = waitHandle;
```

Comment: Naturally it is also necessary to set `EnableRaisingEvents`, but this whole approach is needlessly wasteful when [the OS process handle is already waitable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/synchronization-objects).

Answer (score 2):

A process handle is not naturally awaitable nor does it sit in the same inheritance tree as WaitHandle.  You need to wrap it in an event (which does extend WaitHandle), e.g.:

```
 ManualResetEvent resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(true);
 resetEvent.SafeWaitHandle = new SafeWaitHandle(new IntPtr(process.Handle.ToPointer()), false);
 waitHandles[1] = = resetEvent;
```

All WaitHandle implementations will use a SafeWaitHandle: ["The SafeWaitHandle class is used by the System.Threading.WaitHandle class. It is a wrapper for Win32 mutexes and auto and manual reset events."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeWaitHandle(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Wouldn't `resetEvent.SafeWaitHandle =` leak the event [made by the constructor](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/eventwaithandle.cs,69)?